# Ruby Method Return Best Practice

Tags: ruby

I have a method that looks at variables and returns depending upon what those variables are:

```
def os_detect(os, zone)
  if os.start_with?('centos')
      unless zone == 'aws'
        if os == 'centos7'
            #puts "Not available yet"
            return nil
        end
      end
  else
      #puts "Invalid OS Type"
      return nil
  end
  return true
end
```

I'm building for CLI and Rails so I'm trying to get rid of puts...but I still want to explain to the user what's going on.

Should I just return the strings and true if nothing is blocking?

Is there a better way to handle this type of logic in Ruby?

**UPDATE :** The main purpose of my question was to understand how to pass context to a user based on the logic.

So this method returns *false* for centos7 on aws, or ANY other OS besides centos*.

How does the user know what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: "functions" are called methods in Ruby. In which Class/Module is this method? Where do those instance variables come from?

Comment: what do you expect from this? :) `@zone.nil? == 'aws'`

Comment: @ndn I thought so too at first. It is reachable, with `@os='centosX'` for example.

Comment: Sorry guys. Renamed to methods and fixed the zone logic. The instance variables are loaded earlier into my class. This function is included afterwards.

Comment: Any reason why you return `nil` instead of `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

#### Just booleans

If I understand your code correctly, every `'centos'` is supported except `'centos7'` in zone outside `'aws'`.

```
def os_supported?(os, zone = '')
  os.start_with?('centos') && (zone == 'aws' || os != 'centos7')
end
```

#### Booleans and warning messages

It might be a good idea to use 2 methods : one returns a warning when needed, the other returns `nil` or `true`.

```
def os_support_warning(os, zone = '')
  return 'Invalid OS Type'   unless os.start_with?('centos')
  return 'Not available yet' if os == 'centos7' && zone != 'aws'
end

def os_supported?(os, zone = '')
  warning = os_support_warning(os, zone)
  if warning
    puts warning
  else
    true
  end
end
```

If you accept getting `true/false` instead of `true/nil`, you could use :

```
def os_supported?(os, zone = '')
  warning = os_support_warning(os, zone)
  puts warning if warning
  warning.nil?
end
```

Both `false` and `nil` are falsey : for boolean logic, they're perfectly equivalent.

## Test

To check that our methods are equivalent, I use :

```
%w(centos6 centos7 windows macosx).each do |os|
  %w(aws not_aws).each do |zone|
    @os = os
    @zone = zone
    puts '--------------------------'
    puts "OS : #{os}\t Zone : #{zone}"
    puts "#######BAD#######" if os_detect != os_supported?(os, zone) 
  end
end
```

It outputs

```
--------------------------
OS : centos6     Zone : aws
--------------------------
OS : centos6     Zone : not_aws
--------------------------
OS : centos7     Zone : aws
--------------------------
OS : centos7     Zone : not_aws
Not available yet
Not available yet
--------------------------
OS : windows     Zone : aws
Invalid OS Type
Invalid OS Type
--------------------------
OS : windows     Zone : not_aws
Invalid OS Type
Invalid OS Type
--------------------------
OS : macosx  Zone : aws
Invalid OS Type
Invalid OS Type
--------------------------
OS : macosx  Zone : not_aws
Invalid OS Type
Invalid OS Type
```

They all return the same boolean with the same warning.

Comment: For a method called `os_supported?`, I'd argue that falsey is good enough.

Comment: Answer updated, it should behave exactly the same as the OP's method now.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer this more abstractly. The way I see it, you are asking two things:

1. How to simplify boolean expressions?
2. What syntactical construction to use so that you can add some additional side effects (in this case printing)?

## How to simplify boolean expressions?

Just translate the English sentence to Ruby. There is usually 1:1 mapping. The oposite is also true - you can read your Ruby code as an English sentence to hear if it actually sounds understandable. First, lets read your current implementation:

```
def os_detect(os, zone)
  if os.start_with?('centos')
    unless zone == 'aws'
      if os == 'centos7'
        return nil
      end
    end
  else
    return nil
  end
  return true
end
```

> If the OS is *centos*, unless on *aws* if the OS is *centos7* this feature is not available, otherwise - your OS is considered invalid. If not - we do support this environment.

Even with punctuation (or indentation in the code's case) you have to stop and think for a bit to extract the essence of it. Yes, code unlike English has the perk of being *unambiguous*, but this does not make it *understandable*.

Now lets try to translate English to Ruby. In your own words:

> This method returns `false` for *centos7* on *aws*, or ANY other OS besides *centos*

```
def os_detect(os, zone) # "this method"
  return false if os =='centos7' && zone == 'aws' || !os.start_with?('centos')
end
```

Now you might see that your description didn't match what you actually wanted. That is because what you actually wanted to say was:

> This method determines *whether or not* we run *centos7* on *aws* or any other OS besides *centos*

```
def os_detect(os, zone) # "this method"
  os =='centos7' && zone != 'aws' || !os.start_with?('centos')
end
```

---

## What syntactical construction to use so that you can add some aditional side effects (in this case printing)?

That again depends on how you want to structure your sentence. Mainly you will be using either guard conditions before the final `return` or prints in the actual conditions (similarly to what you did, but readable). Lets try:

> This method says that the feature is not yet available if checking for *centos7* *not* on *aws*. It says that the target OS is invalid unless checking for *centos*. Finally, it determines *whether or not* we run *centos7* *not* on *aws* or any other OS besides *centos*.

```
def os_detect(os, zone) # "this method"
  puts 'Not available yet' if os == 'centos7' and zone != 'aws'
  puts 'Invalid OS Type' unless os.start_with?('centos')

  os =='centos7' && zone != 'aws' || !os.start_with?('centos')
end
```

> This method says that the feature is not yet available and exits if checking for *centos7* *not* on *aws*. It says that the target OS is invalid and exists unless checking for *centos*. If gives the green light otherwise.

```
def os_detect(os, zone) # "this method"
  if os == 'centos7' and zone != 'aws'
    puts 'Not available yet'
    return
  end

  unless os.start_with?('centos')
    puts 'Invalid OS Type'
    return
  end

  true
end
```

Comment: I like the explanation, but the methods all seem to fail for some pairs of 'os,zone'. Also, `and` should probably never be used, and this is no exception. I was hopeful that your example would be a counter-example, but no : your last method always returns `true`.

Comment: Fun fact : you could replace `and` by `or` twice in your last method in order to fix it. It doesn't make it more readable, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil, fixed ^^